# Finding 3 equally spaced boolean cells

Tags: algorithms, complexity

```
Given an array A[N] of N booleans, return a, b such that a >= 0, b > 0 and
A[a] = true
A[a+b] = true
A[a+2b] = true
or -1 if they don't exist.
```

The best algorithm I could find was brute forcing the entire search space, O(n^2) and I wanted to know if there's a better algorithm.

Answer (score 0):

I found an answer on Stack Overflow https://stackoverflow.com/a/1585303/1247066
TL;DR - use FFT & a mathematical property of 2b = c-a